# Recommended way for logging in apollo-server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Apollo server does not seem to ship with any sort of logging. This makes it difficult to use in production environments as is - it is practically running blind. Is there any recommended way to enable different types of logs?

I am specifically looking at seeing verbose logs, error logs (when server crashes / internal component crashes) and other debug logs.

Update:
I am already using `winston` for logging basic events. This question is related to detailed logging - like logging various parts of a request lifecycle, server crash, cache errors, etc.

Comment: I am just practically `console.log` for every endpoint that I hit or `console.warn` or `console.error` if something happens. Apollo provides a tool called `[Apollo Engine](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/features/developer-tooling/#apollo-engine)`, I don't know it has logging features or not, but looks like it provides like metrics.

Answer (score 6):

There is only experimental API at the moment for more precise logging. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/metrics/#granular-logs

```
const { ApolloServer }  = require('apollo-server');
const LoggingExtension = require('./logging');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  extensions: [() => new LoggingExtension()]
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

check out on apollo official GitHub for `logging` file sample:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/8914b135df9840051fe81cc9224b444cfc5b61ab/packages/apollo-server-core/src/logging.ts

I suggest creating a logging extension and use inside one of:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan

You will be able to manage your logs as you want.

- Turn on/off by environment (production/development/staging/etc.)
- pipe logs to files or stdout/stderr or else
- have log "levels" node's console is logging to stdout/stderr only

Check this article: https://www.coreycleary.me/should-you-use-a-logging-framework-or-console-log-in-node/

P.S. While this is an experimental API it will probably be changed. While it's already documented a bit, probably it won't be changed drastically but you never know. I would not recommend investing too many resources working with it atm.

Comment: I was asking specifically for apollo-server. I am using winston right now for basic logs. Maybe I should update the question to make this obvious.

Comment: With the graphql perspective i suggest to use the apollo plugins.

Answer (score 1):

For logging in **Apollo Server** You can set up fine-grained operation logging in Apollo Server by defining a custom plugin. Apollo Server plugins enable you to perform actions in response to individual phases of the GraphQL request lifecycle, such as whenever a GraphQL request is received from a client.
Below is the example. You just need to add logging library instead of console.log in order to get complete logs from lifecycle of Apollo server.

```
const myPlugin = {
  // Fires whenever a GraphQL request is received from a client.
  async requestDidStart(requestContext) {
   console.log('Request started!)
   

    return {
      // Fires whenever Apollo Server will parse a GraphQL
      // request to create its associated document AST.
      async parsingDidStart(requestContext) {
        console.log('Parsing started!');
      },

      // Fires whenever Apollo Server will validate a
      // request's document AST against your GraphQL schema.
      async validationDidStart(requestContext) {
        console.log('Validation started!');
      },

    }
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [
    myPlugin
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `Apollo Log` extension this is an option for graphql logging. What i observed is the issue is when we use it with apollo gateway its not working.

**Apollo log**

https://github.com/shellscape/apollo-log

Answer (score -1):

Apollo GraphQL plugins can provide the functionality of logging. It can provide the support on responding to events also. This is the ideal way for doing it.

Refer -  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/

**Implementation Example**

```
/* Defining the Apollo Server */
const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  schema: gqlSchema
  subscriptions: {
    path: '/subscriptions',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      requestDidStart: ( requestContext ) => {
        if ( requestContext.request.http?.headers.has( 'x-apollo-tracing' ) ) {
          return;
        }
        const query = requestContext.request.query?.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' ).trim();
        const variables = JSON.stringify( requestContext.request.variables );
        console.log( new Date().toISOString(), `- [Request Started] { query: ${ query }, variables: ${ variables }, operationName: ${ requestContext.request.operationName } }` );
        return;
      },
    },
  ]
});
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Be sure to put the plugins in the ApolloServer property and not in the ApolloGateway. I was putting them in the gateway and the logging didnt work...